# Which Linux for my old laptop: Intel Pentium N3540 quad core, 4 gigs RAM

Tags: linux

After a long research on internet, i didn't got proper answer. So I'm writing here. I am about to install Linux distribution on my low spec laptop. I thought of installing Linux mint cinnamon 19.1. Since it is the latest one, i couldn't be sure that whether it's going to run smoothly or not. Currently i have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS which is quite slow. So before i download Linux mint, i want to make sure that it meats hardware requirements. 
Laptop Specs:
Intel Pentium N3540 quad core processor(2.16GHz),
5400 RPM HDD,
4GB DDR3L Ram(1333MHz)

So can this one run Linux mint 19.1 cinnamon smoothly?
If not, may Mate work fine?
Thanks..

Comment: MATE needs definitively fewer resources (especially RAM) than Cinnamon... but with 4GB everything - whether MATE, Cinnamon or Gnome -  should run fine! **||** probably the issue was missing hardware-acceleration resp. a driver with support for it for your graphic card. so either have a look for driver with hardware-acceleration for your graphic card or just use a DE which don't uses hardware-acceleration like MATE: https://askubuntu.com/a/779418/354350

Comment: Lubuntu is a light wight version of Ubuntu. Maybe it is worth as shot. https://lubuntu.net/

Comment: That's almost the specs of my machine which runs Mint Cinnamon – with the difference that I only have a dual-core CPU but 8GB RAM. Apart from that, I have Mint 19.1 running in a VM on that very same machine (needed for preparing some articles, testing stuff etc) which only has 2GB. But "smoothly" certainly depends on the load – so maybe you [edit] your question and include what tasks it must be up to? "Light tasks" (web browsing, mails etc) shouldn't matter much, but heavy ones (e.g. Video editing) would make a difference (but then, that would need more RAM anyway).

Comment: @BasilBourque Why not "Improve Edit", I thought I changed all the little i's to capital I's, and I know I changed "meat" to "meet." And isn't the `linux-distribution` tag more appropriate? It says *Use this tag when seeking recommendations about which Linux distribution is suitable for a specific use-case*, while the `linux` tag is only for software to run on Linux, isn't it?

Comment: What exactly was slow about your Ubuntu? And what are you going to be doing on the laptop, any specific applications, gaming, movies, etc? @Rajesh

Comment: @Xen2050 Why am I flagged on your comment? I’ve no idea what it is about.

Comment: I had edited the Q more extensively earlier, but the only edit now appears to be yours, I was guessing that it was in the Review queue, but didn't get "Improve Edit"ed? But I may have been mistaken

Answer (score 1):

Based on several laptops with similar specs, *Lubuntu* is not too bad.  The hardware support for [*Lubuntu*](https://lubuntu.net/) compiled for *x86* tends to be more stable on old laptops than *AMD64* is.  So for minimal frustration try *Lubuntu* for *x86*.